# JSON Jackson serialize deserialize List of List

Tags: java, json, jackson

I use Json-Jackson to serialize/deserialize my object and all goes well with built-in classes.
String, int, and so on are very good. But now I must serialize/deserialize an object built in a particular manner. Follow the declaration:

```
class A implements Serializable {  
   private String id;
   private List<B> bobjs;
   ...getters & setters (but not for String id)
}
class B implements Serializable {
   private String id;
   private String label;
   private List<C> cobjs;
   ...getters & setters (but not for String id)
}
class C implements Serializable {
   private String id;
   private String label;
   private BigDecimal counts;
   ...getters & setters (but not for String id)
}
```

If I use the standard serializer/deserialize, it says to me an error message like " java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException..." so it cannot serialize/deserialize bobjs.
How can I do this in a general manner, so I do not write 3 serializer/deserializer, but only tell to Json-Jackson when encounter an object of type "List" it must serialize/deserialize it like an array (for example).
Thanks all!

P.S. I find examples on google, but they are only for simple object but not for List that are formed of List.. and so on.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Include your custom serializers (if any), and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Could you add source code and example objects? I think, yours problem is not related with Jackson. If you still need help from our side, please, improve your question.

Comment: The full stacktrace is:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (through reference chain: TheResult["customData"]->java.util.HashMap["Datas"]->Data["bobjs"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->B["cobjs"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a really deep object not serializable. Really deep and little. Thanks all.